# Problems with uploading to font forge from illustrator

Tags: fonts, typography, glyphs

I’m relatively new in the font business so I guess please try to keep it fairly simple. I just finished designing my font in illustrator and whenever I go to export it as SVG and then upload it into font forge, It’s coming up with an error, saying that my file is “too corrupt to upload.” I’ve tried manually importing each glyph and it will just show a blank box, but when I open the box up, it will show the letter. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Tech support for errors/bugs/corrupted files is generally off topic here because they are often dependent on specific files.  It's hard to say why FontForge considers the SVG to be corrupt. Also what is the exact wording of the error message?  If I was to make a guess, make sure your glyph is a compound path with a fill, and no stroke, and that all paths are closed. Try that for starters.

Comment: Fontforge also works better with eps. Anyway describe what you have done. As now your question is does not work.